# Rails route: pull entire path string into one parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've just added a CMS to my rails 2.2.2 app.  I want to have it set up so that at the bottom of my routes i have a catch-all which shoves the entire path into a single parameter and then calls the cms controller, which then looks for a page matching that path

eg

```
http://mysite.com/something/about/foo
=> {:controller => "cms", :action => "show", :page => "something/about/foo"}
```

I can't figure out what options i need to add (if any) to stop it splitting on the slashes.   Any ideas anyone?  Remember this is rails 2.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered the answer to this in the official rails api documentation (doh):

```
4.9 Route Globbing
Route globbing is a way to specify that a particular parameter should be matched
to all  the remaining parts of a route. For example

map.connect 'photo/*other', :controller => 'photos', :action => 'unknown',
```

In my case:

```
map.connect   "/*page", :controller => "cms", :action => "show"
```

means that

```
http://mysite.com/something/about/foo
=> {:controller => "cms", :action => "show", :page => ["something", "about", "foo"]}
```

which is fine as i can easily then join params[:page] to get the full path again.

thanks for reading :)